# How do we use FileMode.Append on C#?

Tags: c#

I've been trying to come up with a way for my code to open a file or create one (if my given file name is non-existent). Afterwards, it will run a program that will end up creating an array and I want the contents of that array to be converted into string and appended into the file that I am creating and opening. I've got everything right except for the 'Append' part. It say in the end that the "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." Can you please enlighten me on this one? Help will be much appreciated.

```
        try
        {
            FileStream fs = new FileStream("inventory.ini", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read);
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fs);

            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                string line = reader.ReadLine();
                string[] data = line.Split('|');
                int code = int.Parse(data[0]);
                string name = data[1];
                double price = double.Parse(data[2]);

                Item item = new Item(code, name, price);
                app.array[inventoryCount++] = item;    
            }

            reader.Close();
            fs.Close();
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }

        app.Run();

        try
        {
            FileStream fs = new FileStream("inventory.ini", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fs);

            foreach (Item item in app.array)
            {
                writer.WriteLine(item.Code + "|" + item.Name + "|" + item.Price);
            }

            writer.Close();
            fs.Close();
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Which line is the exception occurring on?

Comment: It's occurring after the app.Run(). It says that the file can't be accessed because it's being used by another process.

Comment: But in the question you said it was "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: @KendallFrey: See my answer. It's his another take.

Answer (score 2):

You can use another constructor of [StreamWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36b035cb.aspx), that allows appending, and then write like this:

```
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("inventory.ini", true);
```

I never used FileStream in my apps, but StreamWriter has been quite reliable. You can also switch to `Using` statement, then you don't need to `Close()`.

Also I suggest switching to [lists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx), then you will always have the exact amount of items you need inside `app.array` (which btw needs a better name). So this:

```
app.array[inventoryCount++] = item;
```

will change to something like this:

```
app.list.Add(item);
```

Aside from memory management headache relief, you no longer need `inventoryCount` variable, since you can get this value from `list.Count`;

The general approach here is to minimize amount of code you need to write, for the same amount of functionality. Then you have no place for the error to lurk.

Comment: @JeffMercado: Not sure how multiple AppendText would affect the file open state. I have a feeling that it may end up being opened and closed several times, which may not be the intended behavior. Sometimes streams are good.

Comment: Bah, I ruined my comment. Anyway, my point was that you should favor the factory methods in the `File` class instead of using those constructors. It has a much more clearer intent on what it's doing.

Comment: It changed a bit when I used the new constructor. The error now says that the file cannot be accessed because it is being used by another process.

Comment: @joseminicario: Mostly likely cause you were debugging and it never reached Close() in one of the iterations. You need something like a [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to find out and possibly kill any open handles to the file. Or reboot the system for a clean experiment. Now at least the error makes sense.

Comment: @JeffMercado: You suggest use of StringBuilder and then bulk write everything in one shot after the for loop?

Comment: My original comment was suggesting to use the `File.AppendText()` factory method to create the writer, instead of invoking that constructor.

Comment: @JeffMercado: Sorry then, I thought you meant `File.AppendAllText` for some reason. Yes, it's more intuitive from the point that you open a text file for Append, inferred from method name. What's confusing is that a `StreamWriter` is returned. See below answer - for someone who never dealt with IO, it's not apparent that `writer` is of type StreamWriter.

Comment: @everyone Sorry if I can't properly address your comment/suggestion. I can't understand some of your jargon.

Comment: @joseminicario: Don't be afraid to ask. Everyone was a beginner at some point.

Answer (score 2):

```
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
```

You are digging yourself a pretty deep hole with exception handling like this.  A hard rule in catching an exception is that you restore the state of your program when you handle it.  You don't.  In particular, you are forgetting to close the file.  This then goes wrong, later, when you try to open the file again to write.  The exception message is misleading, unfortunately, talking about another process having the file already opened.  Not the case, it is *your* process that still has the file opened.

There are plenty of countermeasures against this failure.  You should be using the *using* statement to ensure the file is closed even if there's an exception.  And you'll need to fix your EndOfStream test, it isn't accurate on text files, use a while(true) loop and break when ReadLine() returns null.  Which solves the original problem.

But the real fix is to not hide an inconvenient truth.  Allowing your program to continue running when a config file is broken just begets more trouble when it doesn't do what you hope it does.  And you can't tell because the message you write to the console was scrolled off the screen.  **Very** hard to diagnose.

Remove the try/catch from this code.  Now you get to address the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you can also just use [`File.AppendText()`](http://File.AppendText) to open a `StreamWriter` in append mode.

You should also use `using` instead of `.Close()` to close the stream - then it will work even if an exception occurs.

So your code would look more like this:

```
try
{
    using (var writer = File.AppendText("inventory.ini"))
    {
        foreach (Item item in app.array)
        {
            if (item != null)
                writer.WriteLine(item.Code + "|" + item.Name + "|" + item.Price);
        }
    }
}

catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

Comment: I tried replication your code and it still returns "Object reference not set to an instance of the object." Thanks, though.

Comment: @joseminicario I think you have a different bug where you have made `app.array` bigger than the number of items that you read into it, so when you try to write them out you get a `null` item in the array once you reach the last item you read in. I have modified my code above to protect against that (see the `if (item != null)`) - does that help?

Comment: @joseminicario: Right, although I believe the solution may be more complex than that. Anyway, I suggest you use Lists instead. No memory management - no headache.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use *using statement*

```
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("inventory.ini", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read))
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fs))
    {
       // do stuff
    }
```